# unique_ptr<> causes compliation errors in C++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am using this library: https://github.com/Agamnentzar/bluetooth-serial-port

```
BTSerialPortBinding::Create(address, channelID)

    Returns new instance of BTSerialPortBinding object

    address: string containint bluetooth address of the device
    channelID: ID of the serial port channel
```

I have a statement:

`unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding>bt(BTSerialPortBinding::Create(d1.address, 1));`

When I separate the statement with the declaration in ArduinoDevice.h and initialisation in ArduinoDevice.cpp in constructor like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt; 
bt.reset(BTSerialPortBinding::Create("93:83:, 1));
```

When I added these statements I got the following error:

```
ArduinoDevice &ArduinoDevice::operator =(const ArduinoDevice &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Relevant bit in Process.cpp file which is referenced by the error

```
dev = ArduinoDevice("/dev/tty.IP-DevB");
```

Process.h

```
#ifndef __PROCESS_H
#define __PROCESS_H

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include "ResonantLowpassFilter.h"

#include "ArduinoDevice.h"

//==============================================================================
/**
*/
class AudioProcessor  : public AudioProcessor
{
public:
    //==============================================================================
    WahwahAudioProcessor();
    ~WahwahAudioProcessor();

    void prepareToPlay (double sampleRate, int samplesPerBlock);
    void releaseResources();

    void processBlock (AudioSampleBuffer& buffer, MidiBuffer& midiMessages);

    AudioProcessorEditor* createEditor();
    int getNumParameters();
    int getNumPrograms();
    int getCurrentProgram();
    void setCurrentProgram (int index);
    const String getProgramName (int index);
    void changeProgramName (int index, const String& newName);



    float centreFrequency_, q_;
    void updateFilterArduino();

    ArduinoDevice dev; //instance to an Arduino device from which sensor data is read

};

#endif  // _PROCESS
```

ArduinoDevice.h

```
#ifndef ArduinoDevice_h
#define ArduinoDevice_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "BTSerialPortBinding.h"
#include <memory>

class ArduinoDevice
{
public:
    ArduinoDevice(const char *dev="");

    void connect();

    void start(void);
    void stop(void);
    void read(void);

    /**
     Disconnects from Arduino device
     **/
    ~ArduinoDevice();

private:
    const char *device; //port address of the device (e.g. "/dev/tty.FireFly-E552-SPP")

    std::unique_ptr<BTSerialPortBinding> bt; //bt serial port 

    void close(void);

};

#endif
```

Edit:

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 and Microsoft's C++ Compiler. I am also using an extra JUCE library(https://www.juce.com/).

`dev = ArduinoDevice("/dev/tty.IP-DevB"));`

dev is declared in the Process.h file above its an instance of ArduinoDevice

My constructor looks like this:

```
ArduinoDevice::ArduinoDevice(const char *dev)
{
    device = dev;
    bt.reset(BTSerialPortBinding::Create("98:D3:31:FD:11:1A", 1));
}
```

I've now tried this in ArduinoDevice.cpp and declaration .h but I still get the same error as above:

```
ArduinoDevice&&(const char *dev);   
{
    data = dev.data;
    dev.data = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: In the line `dev = ArduinoDevice("/dev/tty.IP-DevB"); `,  what is `dev`? (show its declaration)

Comment: `dev` is also mentioned in `bt.reset(BTSerialPortBinding::Create(dev, 1));`. I guess you are using the same name `dev` for two different things, this is confusing

Comment: Also show what compiler and commandline you use

Comment: (BTW if you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the site posting guidelines recommend, then we do not have to ask all these questions)

Comment: this is correct dev in this instance can be ignored because I have replaced it with a hard coded alternative it just takes char* I will rename for convenience thank you --  I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

`unique_ptr` is not copyable. So when you declare it as a member of your class, your class becomes non-copyable too. The error exactly points that out. (Copy assignment operator is deleted because of that).

Note that usually the move assignment operator is automatically generated by the compiler for you. But in your case since you've explicitly defined a destructor for your class, compiler cant safely define a move assignment operator (or constructor) for you.

Comment: `dev = ArduinoDevice("/dev/tty.IP-DevB");` would be a move operation, so it should not invoke copy assignment. OP is leaving out something important.

Comment: @M.M Since the class has a explicitly defined destructor, no move assignment operator will be generated by the compiler. Thus the error.

Comment: What can I do instead to reference an ArduinoDevice object?

Comment: @Als Have compiler generate move operators for you (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457344.aspx for MSVC). You should decide if your class can be copied or not. If yes, you probably need a shallow copy, and you need to declare your own copy assignment. If no, then don't copy it!

Comment: unique_ptr can't be shallow copied. Adding move assignment (and move construction) is the right solution

Comment: In which header or .cpp would I add the move assignment and construction? @M.M

Comment: @Als They must be part of ArduinoDevice

Comment: @Mohammad I've edited my question with what I tried but still get the same error could you take a look?